# ROS Kinetic 64Bit with 32Bit library

Tags: ros, library, ros-kinetic, 64bit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit6:
I found now the way to download the 32bit libraries and i tried it with the libroscpp. and it works but now he needs much more libraries. Is there a way to download all libraries with one package?!

I tried to download the libroscpp.so and it works fine with the followin commands:

- apt-get download ros-kinetic-roscpp:i386
- Extract the archieve and get the lib from the data.tar.

Then I used the lib for compiling a node an now he needs all the other libraries like librosconsole.so. So my question is if there is a easy way to download all 32bit libraries with one step?!

---

Hi
I started some days ago with ROS. I'm using a 64bit Ubuntu system and the installation of ROS Kinetic works fine and I'm able to build an node and to start the node. Now I need to use a library which only exists in a 32Bit version. I use the linker flag -m32 to use the library but then I have the problem with the 64Bit ROS libraries. So I need the ROS libraries in a 32Bit version but i found currently no way to install them or to build them myself! I wrote in the forum that this problem was already discussed but i found no working answer. Has someone a solution for this problem? THANKS

---

Edit: Hi
Thanks for the reply. I need a system with a 64bit version of Kinetic for the ROS nodes but one node is a 32 bit node thats the reason why I need the 32 libraries. I compiled it myself and it works perfect for 64 bit. I tried to compile the 32 bit version but it doesn't work. I used:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --cmake-args -CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-m32" --install
```

How does it work correctly?!

---

Edit 2: Hi
I have a already running ROS system ob a normal Ubuntu and everthing runs with 64 bit. Now I have to integrate another ROS node that uses a 32 bit library. I understand that the node must be a 32 bit node otherwise I can not use the 32bit library. But the node must run in the 64bit environment. So I need the ROS librarys in 32bit to link them against the 32bit node. I downloaded the source code but when I try the commanline:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --cmake-args -CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-m32" --install
```

I got the error message

CMake Error: Error processing file: MAKE_C_FLAGS=-m32

So I am currently only able to compile the 64bit version!

---

Edit 3: Hi
I know that there are 32Bit Libs for the kinetic version but I need the 64bit Version on my system and at the same time the 32bit version. Is this possible?! I tried to install the 32 bit version but it didn't work.

```
enter@ubuntu:~/Downloads/ros_catkin_ws$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-desktop-full:i386 : Depends: ros-kinetic-desktop:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: ros-kinetic-perception:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

Edit 4: Hi
My goal is that I am able to build the node and provide the used 32bit librarys for the node. Then I would install the librarys and the node on the target with the 64bit system to communicate with the master there. Is that not possible? I want to avoid to use a docker or something else.

---

Edit 5: Hi
Yes thats true I got a library for a hardware and they don't provide a 64Bit version. So I have to write a 32Bit ROS node. I can also not change the rest of the ROS system because this already exists. I know that it would be much easier if the library exists in 64 bit. I already try to build a 32bit ROS library but the console bridge config makes problems!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283547/ros-kinetic-64bit-with-32bit-library/) by [Fresh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33841/fresh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit7:

> I found now the way to download the 32bit libraries and i tried it with the libroscpp. and it works but now he needs much more libraries. Is there a way to download all libraries with one package?!

I believe this would be best asked in a new question, as otherwise we start to meander into new topics in this one.

But any answer to your edit would depend on what you are currently doing to "download the 32bit libraries".

---

Edit6:

> Hi My goal is that I am able to build the node and provide the used 32bit librarys for the node. Then I would install the librarys and the node on the target with the 64bit system to communicate with the master there. Is that not possible? I want to avoid to use a docker or something else.

To my knowledge -- and based on the information that you've provided -- this is not possible without some form of isolation between your 64bit and 32bit runtime environments. A chroot or similar system (like Docker, LXC, etc) could provide that.

Building ROS Kinetic from source for 32bit could work, but only if all the dependencies for that are available in 32bit *and* support multiarch. I don't know whether that is the case.

Note that this is not a ROS specific problem at all, it would be a problem with any framework trying to mix 64 and 32 bit objects.

I'm assuming the library that you have to use was given to you (by an mfg fi) and you have to work with it. Otherwise, I'd suggest trying to obtain a 64bit version of it, as that will make everything significantly easier.

---

Edit5:

> I know that there are 32Bit Libs for the kinetic version but I need the 64bit Version on my system and at the same time the 32bit version. Is this possible?!

No, unfortunately you cannot install both the `i386` and the `amd64` packages, as it appears the ROS pkgs don't seem to support [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO).

Building from source would be an option, but it will require that all your dependencies *do* support multiarch. Without that, even adding `-m32` will most likely not solve your problem.

If this is just a single node, you could perhaps look into using a suitable Docker image containing a 32bit OS and build it in there and run it from a container. Docker containers can communicate with the host quite easily via network, and ROS nodes don't really care where they are run, as long as they can communicate with the master (which would be running on the host) and other nodes.

---

Edit4:

> ```
>  ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --cmake-args -CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-m32" --install
> ```
>
> I got the error message
>
> ```
> CMake Error: Error processing file: MAKE_C_FLAGS=-m32
> ```

I'm still not sure whether you actually need to build all of ROS from source (as there are still 32bit pkgs available), but to set that CMake variable you'll need to use the `-D` option, like so:

```
--cmake-args -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-m32"
```

But that will make `gcc` compile *everything* for a 32bit target, which may not be what you want.

---

Edit3:

> I need a system with a 64bit version of Kinetic for the ROS nodes but one node is a 32 bit node thats the reason why I need the 32 libraries. I compiled it myself and it works perfect for 64 bit. I tried to compile the 32 bit version but it doesn't work

I don't really understand what you're trying to say. "Does not work" is not enough information to help you.

You cannot link 32bit libraries into 64bit binaries or the other way around. If you need to work with a 32bit library, I believe you have no other option to build a 32bit node as well.

Adding `-m32` to your flags could be a way to do that, but it depends on what other stuff you have in your workspace. To make this a package-local setting, I'd try to add this to the appropriate `CMakeLists.txt` (the one of the package). But you'll probably need to have certain parts of the 32bit distribution of ROS (and other libraries) on your system as well.

---

Edit2:

> So I need the ROS libraries in a 32Bit version but i found currently no way to install them

There should still be 32bit binaries for Kinetic - only for Lunar and newer releases the 32bit builds have been removed (see also [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019)).

See the [overview page](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) of the Kinetic installation docs for Ubuntu Xenial: it has columns for both `amd64` as well as `i386`.

However: by default, an `amd64` installation of Ubuntu will *only* install 64bit packages, even if the repository contains other architectures. You'll have to enable the `i386` architecture and then ask `apt` to install `i386` packages *explicitly*. See [Installing 32-bit libraries on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus](https://blog.teststation.org/ubuntu/2016/05/12/installing-32-bit-software-on-ubuntu-16.04/) for a page that describes how to do this.

I can't guarantee that it'll work, but in a nutshell:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install some-ros-package:i386
```

> or to build them myself!

Source install instructions can be found on the wiki (right next to all other installation instructions): [wiki/kinetic/Installation/Source](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source).

Installation using `deb` packages (for Debian/Ubuntu at least) is however almost always preferred.

> I wrote in the forum that this problem was already discussed but i found no working answer

Which forum are you referring to here?

---

Edit:

> I need a system with a 64bit version of Kinetic for the ROS nodes but one node is a 32 bit node thats the reason why I need the 32 libraries. I compiled it myself and it works perfect for 64 bit. I tried to compile the 32 bit version but it doesn't work

I don't really understand what you're trying to say. "Does not work" is not enough information to help you.

You cannot link 32bit libraries into 64bit binaries or the other way around. If you need to work with a 32bit library, I believe you have no other option to build a 32bit node as well.

Adding `-m32` to your flags could be a way to do that, but it depends on what other stuff you have in your workspace. To make this a package-local setting, I'd try to add this to the appropriate `CMakeLists.txt` (the one of the package). But you'll probably need to have certain parts of the 32bit distribution of ROS (and other libraries) on your system as well.

---

> So I need the ROS libraries in a 32Bit version but i found currently no way to install them

There should still be 32bit binaries for Kinetic - only for Lunar and newer releases the 32bit builds have been removed (see also [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019)).

See the [overview page](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) of the Kinetic installation docs for Ubuntu Xenial: it has columns for both `amd64` as well as `i386`.

However: by default, an `amd64` installation of Ubuntu will *only* install 64bit packages, even if the repository contains other architectures. You'll have to enable the `i386` architecture and then ask `apt` to install `i386` packages *explicitly*. See [Installing 32-bit libraries on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus](https://blog.teststation.org/ubuntu/2016/05/12/installing-32-bit-software-on-ubuntu-16.04/) for a page that describes how to do this.

I can't guarantee that it'll work, but in a nutshell:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install some-ros-package:i386
```

> or to build them myself!

Source install instructions can be found on the wiki (right next to all other installation instructions): [wiki/kinetic/Installation/Source](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source).

Installation using `deb` packages (for Debian/Ubuntu at least) is however almost always preferred.

> I wrote in the forum that this problem was already discussed but i found no working answer

Which forum are you referring to here?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-20**:
For a comment on (current) multi-arch support: #q283945.